# Android MediaPlayer Http Stream of mp4 file causes "Unexcepted end of stream" after a few minutes, only on Android 6 (M)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am currently developing an Android app including a video player which loads a mp4 video file via HTTP using android's VideoView.
It works just fine on a Nexus 4 with Android version 5.1.1 as well as on a tablet with Android 4.4 installed.

However, using Android 6.0 the video stream ends unexpectedly after a few minutes (tested on a Nexus 5 and the emulator).
As you can see in the log output, **the stream plays for about 5 minutes until the java.net.ProtocolException** occurs and another 1 minute until the buffer is empty.

```
10-16 11:08:21.030 4657-4657/...app D/video: start
10-16 11:08:21.060 4657-4657/...app W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://someurl...mp4
10-16 11:08:29.330 4657-4657/...app D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
10-16 11:08:29.360 4657-4657/...app D/video: prepared
10-16 11:08:29.470 4657-4671/...app W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (3, 0)
10-16 11:09:19.930 4657-4664/...app W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10ms
10-16 11:14:32.550 4657-4664/...app W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10ms
10-16 11:23:46.940 4657-4671/...app W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 121022400 / 22592 => java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
10-16 11:24:40.780 4657-4669/...app E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1004)
10-16 11:24:40.780 4657-4657/...app E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1004)
10-16 11:24:40.780 4657-4657/...app D/VideoView: Error: 1,-1004
10-16 11:24:40.780 4657-6289/...app E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1004)
10-16 11:24:40.790 4657-4713/...app E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1004)
10-16 11:24:40.830 4657-4657/...app E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1004)
10-16 11:24:40.830 4657-4657/...app D/VideoView: Error: 1,-1004
10-16 11:24:40.840 4657-4657/...app E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1004)
10-16 11:24:40.840 4657-4657/...app D/VideoView: Error: 1,-1004
10-16 11:24:40.860 4657-4697/...app W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-16 11:24:40.860 4657-4697/...app W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe0d7e740, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-16 11:24:40.880 4657-6289/...app E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1004)
10-16 11:24:40.880 4657-4713/...app E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1004)
10-16 11:24:40.890 4657-4697/...app W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-16 11:24:40.890 4657-4697/...app W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe11fbd80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-16 11:24:40.920 4657-4697/...app W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-16 11:24:40.920 4657-4697/...app W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xed7939e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-16 11:24:40.950 4657-4657/...app E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1004)
10-16 11:24:40.950 4657-4657/...app D/VideoView: Error: 1,-1004
10-16 11:24:40.950 4657-4657/...app E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1004)
10-16 11:24:40.950 4657-4657/...app D/VideoView: Error: 1,-1004
10-16 11:24:41.010 4657-4697/...app W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-16 11:24:41.010 4657-4697/...app W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe0ed12e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-16 11:24:41.030 4657-4697/...app W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-16 11:24:41.030 4657-4697/...app W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe0ed1300, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Adding wake and wifi locks did not seem to prevent this behavior.

Here is the layout configuration of the video player fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".VideoActivity"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

    ...
```

And parts of the code:

```
videoView = (VideoView) v.findViewById(R.id.video);
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
videoView.setVideoURI(videoUrl);
videoView.seekTo(0);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the video encoding of the provider, but still only in combination with Android 6.0

Comment: I am streaming audio files with a length of 2-4 hours. After 10-15 minutes I encounter this error on Marshmallow 6.01 too. /MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 78154603 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream